# Not able to downgrade openssl-libs in centOs

Tags: openssl, libcrypto

I am trying to install nginx using "sudo yum install nginx" leading me to below error:

```
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (client)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-19.el7
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (client)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686 (localrepo)
              ~openssl-libs(x86-32) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
```

To solve this I followed the following series of commands:

```
=> yum list openssl-libs --show-duplicates
```

Output:

```
Installed Packages
openssl-libs.x86_64                                                            1:1.0.2k-19.el7                                                                 installed
Available Packages
openssl-libs.i686                                                              1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9                                                             client
openssl-libs.x86_64                                                            1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9                                                             client
openssl-libs.i686                                                              1:1.0.2k-12.el7                                                                 localrepo
```

Then i tried downgrading "openssl" following which I got the below error:

```
Error: Package: erlang-crypto-20.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (@localrepoMoney)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
           Downgraded By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (client)
              ~libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
```

When I try to download lybcrypto.so.10 following error occurs.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.i686 1:1.0.2k-12.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT) for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3 for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT) for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3 for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2 for package: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-libs.i686 0:1.13.2-10.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for openssl-libs which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of openssl-libs of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude openssl-libs.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of openssl-libs installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of openssl-libs installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.i686 != 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64
```

Kindly suggest me how to solve this. I have been stuck on this for very long.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Erlang wasn't installed from an official CentOS repo and uses a newer version of OpenSSL than officially supported by your current version of CentOS. You can try to reinstall Erlang from EPEL repo or uninstall it completely, install a Nginx that supports openssl 1.0.2k (e.g. from EPEL or build it on your own), or upgrade CentOS.